# Image stitching & OCR

Tags: image, ocr, rounding, image-stitching

Picture a piece of metal bar, 20mm long, about 30mm round.  On the bar, there is numbers stamped.  10 characters, 4.5mm high, spread around approximately 120° of the circumference.

I need to perform OCR on the characters BUT the text characters are not all visible in one image.  Three images spaced at around 30° seems to look ok.

Next issue is the metal is freshly machined and the text characters do not seem to OCR well; I think due to the lack of real contrast. ie black/white difference.

Does anyone have any ideas on how these characters could be OCR'd??

Comment: can you post some example pictures?

Comment: Without example pictures it's really hard to give an answer. Even my crystal ball insists on example pictures...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this ImageMagick command to increase 'contrast'. It basically leaves over only 2 values (zero or maximum) for each color. Every value below the threshold gets set to `0`, values above the threshold get set to `255` (or `65535` if working at 16-bit depth):

```
 convert  original.jpg  -threshold 50%  modified.jpg
```

Play with the value of `50%` to get best results -- set it higher or lower... Depending on your input image, this could already be enough to get images that are OK for OCR-ing.